# Access Key of Dictionary inside self

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Is it possible to access the key of a dictionary inside of the same dictionary?

For example, I know this doesn't work, but I want to do something like this:

```
d = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': d['a'] + d['b'] # or actually more like: self.a + self.b
}

print(d['c']) # 3
```

Comment: No, because at that time the dict doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @deceze hmm okay thanks, I assumed this was the case but I wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the derived `(key, value)` pairs after contructing the dict.

```
d = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}
d['c'] = d['a'] + d['b']
```